# How to add a user key pair to openvpn without remaking ca.crt

Tags: openvpn

I recently set up an OpenVPN server and am trying to create a key pair for a new user. I do not want to rebuild ca.key or ca.crt but when i run
easy rsa script build-key i get this:

> Please edit the vars script to reflect your configuration,
>
> then source it with "source ./vars".
>
> Next, to start with a fresh PKI configuration and to delete any
>
> previous certificates and keys, run "./clean-all".
>
> Finally, you can run this tool (pkitool) to build certificates/keys.

I do not want a new ca.key file, I like the one I have, I just want to add users to the existing one.

Is there an easy way to do this? or a hard way, or any way?

Am i being an idiot and running cleanall won't change my server ca.key?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a profile for a new client:

On the server:

```
cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
sudo su
. ./vars
./build-key [keyname]
```

hit return on all prompts till it asks for y/n, answer y to 2 questions

```
cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/client.conf /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/[keyname].ovpn
```

`exit` (to get out of su)

copy these files to the client

```
/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/[keyname].ovpn
/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/[keyname].crt
/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/[keyname].key
/etc/openvpn/ca.crt
```

If your config has `ccd-exclusive` set in `server.conf` don't forget to create an empty file in /ccd with the client name. Can add fixed IP in this file if desired.

Comment: THANKS!!! I was missing  . ./vars all working great now. Thanks you !!

Comment: You are welcome. If this helped you, please mark the answer as correct by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will add to both our reputation and help future questioners.

Comment: Done, sorry new to site, first quotation every answered! May or be the first of many